# Windows forms objects and text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have c# windows form that has n number of text boxes that I can load using

```
txbName1.text = objectA.GetValue("ValueSection","ValueName")
```

or

```
txbName2.text = objectB.GetValue("ValueSection","ValueName")
```

It would make more sense if the textbox was a class based on textbox and called objectA or objectB with a method:-

`this.textGetValueFromObjectCreatedWhenUserClicksAloadInfoButton("A","ValueSection","ValueName")`

or

```
GetValueFromObjectCreatedWhenUserClicksAloadInfoButton("B","ValueSection","ValueName")
```

and if the object is not available textbox stays empty.

Has anyone got/seen an example of this sort of thing please?

Comment: I suppose what I am looking for is the same as MS has built in with databinding textBox.DataBindings.Add()

Comment: You can make your data a binding source by implementing the correct set of interfaces. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983621(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend a textbox you need to do:

```
public class MyTextBox: TextBox
{
    ....
}
```

Now I don't know enough about your model to tell you the rest, but you could make your objects implement an interface similar to this:

```
public interface IMyObjects
{
    string GetValue(string section, string name);
}
```

you'd need to set this object in the textbox and then you can call that in your custom TextBox whenever you need to (e.g. in the OnClick event)